# Taking a screenshot using Selenium, and removing an element from the screenshot

Tags: java, selenium

I am wondering what the best way to approach this problem will be. The approach I had thought of doesn't seem very optimal, and I was hoping someone might have encountered this problem before, or might have a better solution.

My approach seems to be to get the coordinates of my screenshot and the element I am trying to remove, along with the length and width of both my screenshot and the element I am trying to remove. Then I would have to make sure that the element exists at least partially within my screenshot, and set two points at the opposite points of the region that exist within the screenshot, and finally paint over that area.

I am implementing automated layout testing, which will require me to test whether web elements remain the same between tests, while ignoring web elements that may exist inside of these web elements. One example of this may be the Stack Overflow navigation bar. I might expect the logo, help bar and search bar to appear in the same place every time I visit Stack Overflow, but I do not care about the number of inbox messages that I have, and nor do I care about testing the reputation number and the profile image, nor whether I have new achievements.

What would be your approach to this problem?

Comment: What is you reason to remove the element's part from screenshot.And make your question more clear

Comment: I am implementing automated layout testing, which will require me to test whether web elements remain the same between tests, while ignoring web elements that may exist inside of these web elements. One example of this may be the Stack Overflow navigation bar. I might expect the logo, help bar and search bar to appear in the same place every time I visit Stack Overflow, but I do not care about the number of inbox messages that I have, and nor do I care about testing the reputation number and the profile image, nor whether I have new achievements.

Answer (score 0):

Everything what you've asked [*One example of this may be the Stack Overflow navigation bar. I might expect the logo, help bar and search bar to appear in the same place every time I visit Stack Overflow, but I do not care about the number of inbox messages that I have, and nor do I care about testing the reputation number and the profile image, nor whether I have new achievements*] can be achieved easily via [Galen Framework](http://galenframework.com)

Galen is an open-source tool for testing layout and responsive design of web applications. It is also a powerfull functional testing framework.

How does it work?

Galen Framework uses Selenium in order to open web browser and select the tested elements on page. It has a special language to describe the layout of web page for different browser sizes. You just need to define your own tags for devices and sizes and then using the galen spec language write checks for each element on page. The best way to test the layout is to check location and dimensions of elements relatively to each other.